# Core Data GROUP BY

Tags: ios, core-data, ios6, group-by, nsfetchrequest

Trying to do a simple GROUP BY in Core Data, but no succes still. Starting point was here ([Matt Connolly's Blog post of about a year ago](http://mattconnolly.wordpress.com/2012/06/21/ios-core-data-group-by-and-count-results/) and looked all over SO as well.

I simply want to group by a single property:

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Document" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    NSAttributeDescription *chapterDesc = [request.entity.attributesByName objectForKey:@"chapter"];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[chapterDesc]];
    [request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[chapterDesc]];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    // error handling
```

I am not getting any errors, but no results (nil). When debugging with *-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug* it shows the correct SQL statement. (I know Core Data is not SQL but the statement is correct...). I am positive there is data present in the database (simply setting a *predicate = nil* returns all entries).

Does anyone has any ideas (or knows from experience) what my mistake is?

**UPDATE**

As requested, the data model of Document.h:

```
@interface Document : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * chapter;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isDoctor;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * section;

+ (Document *)createOrUpdateDocumentWithChapter:(NSNumber *)chapter section:(NSNumber *)section doctor:(BOOL)doctor inManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
+ (NSArray *)getDocumentsInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;

@end
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you reveal a little more insight about your model (at least Document and chapter).

Comment: Indeed, sorry. I updated the question.